Solving Inequalities of the Type $10x\log_2(x) > 2x^2$
Given inequality $$10x\log_2(x) > 2x^2$$
Simplifying it, I get: $x > 0$ and $10\log_2(x) - 2x > 0$
How do I solve the second inequality? Simplifying it, I end up with :
$$\log_2(x) > \frac{x}{5}$$

In short, there are three options: 1) Using Lambert W function pretty much as you would use a non-monotone $\arcsin$; 2) not doing it; 3) doing it somehow else if possible.

There is no analytical way of solving this inequality.
Setting $$f(x) = 10\log_2(x) - 2x$$
and using derivatives you see that $f$ is strictly increasing for $x \le \frac{5}{\ln(2)}$ and strictly decreasing for $x \ge \frac{5}{\ln(2)}$.
With $$\lim_{x\to 0} =  f(x) = \lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = -\infty$$ and $$f\left(\frac{5}{\ln(2)}\right) > 0$$ it follows that there exists exactly two values $x_1, x_2$ s.t. $f(x_1) = f(x_2) = 0$.
$x_1$ and $x_2$ can be found numericaly and then your equality holds for all $x \in (x_1, x_2)$.
